# Do schizophrenics tend to believe they were gaslighted?

Tags: psychiatry, schizophrenia

It would seem to me that it would be hard for a single person to manipulate a mentally stable into thinking they have schizoid problems. One might quickly become suspicious if the supposed delusions are only tied to a single acquaintance. But for people who are already slightly schizophrenic, it would be much easier to exaggerate their symptoms. Aside from cases of actual intentional gaslightings, schizophrenic people may tend to be paranoid and form beliefs that they are manipulated.

All that is slightly different from the more common situation where a schizophrenic person thinks he is lied to by psychiatrist, psychotherapist or another mental health worker.

Is there any research on the schizophrenic people believing they were [gaslighted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting) by friends, family or another acquaintances? Or at least some case notes or the mental health workers speaking about that issue?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE! I have heard slightly different definitions of gaslighting. Can you please give us your definition for the purposes of the question?  What have you read on the subject of gaslighting and how it may be perceived in schizophrenia?

Comment: I would use such definition, a narrowing of the def. in Wikipedia "a form of manipulation that seeks to sow seeds of doubt in a targeted individual or in members of a targeted group, hoping to make them question their own sanity". I couldn't really find anything about that topic from the psychiatric perspective, only a general Wikipedia article and few webpages speaking about it in little detail.

Comment: I have always had questions about that definition. Like, would simply asking [Socratic questioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_questioning) a form of question their own sanity?